# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: net/sf/cglib/beans/BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey.class

Tags: android, build.gradle, appium-android

How can I resolve the duplicate entry error, for reference I am adding my project gradle detail.

From my side to resolve the error I deleted the cglib manually from .gradle/caches/module-2/files-2.1/cglib  but during build I found that jcenter creates the libs againg. tried to exculde failed on that step

Bellow is my build.gradle file inside app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.keya.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })
    /*androidTestCompile 'com.microsoft.appcenter:appium-test-extension:1.0'*/
    def appCenterSdkVersion = '1.1.0'
    compile "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    compile "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:2.0.0'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.8'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j
    compile group: 'org.apache.james', name: 'apache-mime4j', version: '0.6.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.4.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.4.1'


    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.beust:jcommander:1.27'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.5'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    /*compile files('libs/appium-test-extension-1.0.jar')*/
    compile 'com.microsoft.appcenter:appium-test-extension:1.0'


}


apply plugin: 'maven'

task createPom {
    pom {
        withXml {
            def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

            //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
            configurations.testCompile.allDependencies.each {
                def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
            }

            def profilesNode = asNode().appendNode('profiles')
            profilesNode.append(new XmlParser().parse('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-Test-Appium-Java-Extensions/master/gradleuploadprofilesnippet.xml'))
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")}
```

and in the outside app I have the following build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

can any one suggest how to resolve the problem

Comment: All the `'com.android.support:` dependencies must end with the same number, by the way

Comment: I have added that which you can see ompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'

Comment: First, you don't need that line. Second, the version doesn't match `appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

Comment: You should try deleting all the JAR files in your libs folder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already deleted all the files in lib inside app, also removed the line compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1 but still facing the error

Comment: during build found the following action automatically  Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/cglib/cglib/3.1/cglib-3.1.pom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161868/discussion-between-kumrun-nahar-keya-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Okay, now run the command in the answer, it'll tell you which dependencies included that library more than once

Comment: I have run the cmd but didnt find the cglib in dependency list its automatically downloading automatically Download jcenter.bintray.com/cglib/3.1/cglib-3.1.pom

Comment: Something in your dependencies is getting that. Comment out one at a time, if you have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I solved the problem via checking the dependencies

```
../gradlew dependenci
```

Then found that cglib lib have duplicates so added the following line on app build.gradle file

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'cglib', module: 'cglib'
}
```

thus resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should identify which of the dependencies needs cglib library. You can do it using the following gradle command:

```
gradle dependencies
```

then, use the [exclude](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies) gradle directive on your build.gradle file to remove the cglib lib from all (apart one) of those dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but there is no dependency related to cglib during build  its automatically downloading automatically Download jcenter.bintray.com/cglib/3.1/cglib-3.1.pom